# Highcharts tooltips formatter return function throwing Uncaught TypeError: j.call is not a function

Tags: javascript, highcharts

We have used Highcharts in our one of the module and we want to show a tooltips when a pointer moves over the pie chart slice.

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie'
    },
    colors: [
        '#ff6600',
        '#333300',
        '#660000'],
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter:function () {return '<b>' + this.point.name + '<\/b>';},
shared:true,
headerFormat:"<span style=\"padding:0\">{point.key}: <b{point.percentage:.1f}%<\/b><\/span><br>",
valueDecimals:2,
useHTML:true,
pointFormat:"<span style=\"padding:0\">Count : <b>{point.y:.0f}<\/b>",
enabled:true,
footerFormat:"<\/span>"
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Time',
            data: [
                ["sleep", 10],
                ["work", 30],
                ["play", 10]
            ],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

But console is throwing ***Uncaught TypeError: j.call is not a function*** error.
If we run the same code in [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/ztJkb/50/) then it works as expected.

Comment: fiddle link is incorrect, update it

Comment: are u embeding highcharts into any of ur parent pages ?

Comment: Hi Benil,
Yes this chart page is embedded into another JSP.

Comment: Have you tried to skip using jquery and then [standalone-framwework](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/installation)

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
```

instead of

```
$('#container').highcharts({
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/renderto-object/

Comment: Hi Pandiyan,
Above is not possible in our case. :-(